# Why doesn't this JavaScript function calculate correctly when the site is first loaded, but works fine afterwards?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a site that generates notation for a random musical rhythm based on some user-selected parameters.  It does this by using an ajax call, which returns a random set of `<img>` elements that represent different notes.  I have a function that is designed to scale the rhythm to fit in the screen, regardless of it's actual size.

The function is triggered after a successful ajax call, which is triggered by a click event on a button.

My problem is that the function does not work as desired when running the first time the page is loaded.

After the function runs for the first time, the `height` attribute of all of the `<img>` elements is somehow set to `0`.

However, the function works great if I run the it again (by clicking the button).  It also works fine after a page refresh.

Also, I do not have this issue in IE11, only Chrome (I haven't tested other browsers yet).

I have tried wrapping the code in both `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` event handlers, but this didn't help.

The site in action can be found at http://www.rhythmrandomizer.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the relevant code:

Event handler for the button:

```
$("#randomize").click(function(){
    //get general options from form
    var timeSignature = $("#timeSignature").val();
    var phraseLength = $("#phraseLength").val();

    //get note options from form
    var checked = [];
    $("#noteOptions :checked").each(function() {
        checked.push($(this).val());
    });

    //alert user and exit function if nothing is selected
    if (checked.length < 1) {
        alert("Please select at least one note value");
        return;
    }


    //format note option ids into a delimited string
    var noteOptions = "";
    for (var i=0; i < checked.length; i++) {
        noteOptions += checked[i] + "a";
    }

    //remove the final comma and space
    noteOptions = noteOptions.substr(0, noteOptions.length - 1);

    //ajax call
    $.ajax("randomize.php", {
        data : {
            timeSignature : timeSignature,
            phraseLength : phraseLength,
            noteOptions : noteOptions
        },
        type : "GET",
        success : function(response) {
            $("#rhythm").html(response);
            scaleRhythm();
        },
        error : function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            console.log(status + " | " + errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
});
```

The php file that returns the rhythm notation:

```
<?php
//MySQL connection variables
$hostname = 'localhost';
$user = ini_get('mysqli.default_user');
$pw = ini_get('mysqli.default_pw');
$database = 'rhytxfpd_rhythmrandomizer';

//Connect to database
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $hostname . ';dbname=' . $database,$user,$pw);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

//Get values from GET
$timeSignature = $_GET['timeSignature'];
$phraseLength = $_GET['phraseLength'];
$noteOptString = $_GET['noteOptions'];

//Split up note options string
$noteOptions = explode('a', $noteOptString);

//Create sql query
$sql = 'SELECT
            noteName,
            noteValue,
            noteGraphic
        FROM
            notes
        WHERE';

//append noteOptions as WHERE clauses
foreach ($noteOptions as $opt) {
    $sql = $sql . ' noteGroupID = ' . $opt . ' OR';
}

//remove final " OR"
$sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 3);

//query the database and get all results as an array
/* This will return a table with the name, graphic, and value of 
 * the notes that the user selected prior to submitting the form
 */
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

//Get the total number of options selected
$numOpts = count($result);

/***************************/
/** BEGIN PRINTING RHYTHM **/
/***************************/

//div to begin the first measure
echo '<div class="measure" id="m1' . $measure . '">';

//Print time signature
echo '<img class="note" src="notes/' . $timeSignature . '.png" title="time signature ' . 
        $timeSignature . '/4" alt="time signature ' . $timeSignature . '/4"/>';

//Prints as many measures as indicated by the phrase length selection
$measure = 1;
while ($measure <= $phraseLength) {

    //begin a new div for other measures.
    if ($measure != 1) {
        echo '<div class="measure" id="m' . $measure . '">';
    }

    //Prints random measure according to time signature
    $beats = 0;
    while ($beats < $timeSignature) {
        //Generate a random number
        $random = rand(0, $numOpts - 1);

        //Get the random note from results
        $note = $result[$random];

        //Continues if chosen note will not fit in the measure
        if ($beats + $note['noteValue'] > $timeSignature) {
            continue;
        }

        //Prints random note
        echo '<img class="note" src="notes/' . $note['noteGraphic'] . '.png" title="' .
                $note['noteName'] . '" alt="' . $note['noteName'] . '"/>';

        //Adds random note's value to total number of beats
        $beats += $note['noteValue'];
        //$beats++;
    }

    //If last measure
    if ($measure == $phraseLength) {
        echo '<img class="note" src="notes/1.png" title="double barline" alt="double barline"/>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<img class="note" src=notes/b.png title="barline" alt="barline"/>';
        echo '</div>';
    }

    //Increment to next measure
    $measure++;
}
```

The scaleRhythm() function:

```
function scaleRhythm() {
    //Get width of rhythm at full resolution
    var rhythmWidth = $("#rhythm").width();

    //Get current screen/window width
    var screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

    //Compute ratio between curren screen and window widths
    var ratio =   screenWidth / rhythmWidth;

    //Multiply img note height by ratio, then by 90% to provide some
    //breathing room on either side of the rhythm
    var newHeight = (400 * ratio) * .9;

    //Set img note height to new height or 300px, whichever is smaller
    if (newHeight < 300) {
        $(".note").css("height",newHeight);
        //code to center rhythm horizontally
        $("#rhythm").css("margin-top",(300-newHeight)/2);
    } else {
        $(".note").css("height",300);
        $("#rhythm").css("margin-top",0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where the function is being called on page load. Try adding `$(function(){ scaleRhythm(); });` to your script tag - this will run the `scaleRhythm()` function once the page is loaded.

Comment: A zero height/width means you are reading the style of a hidden element most likely.

Comment: @JRulle, the function is called when clicking a button, not on page load. However, it does not work the first time I click it after the page loads for the first time. It works on every subsequent click, and also works after refreshing the page.

Comment: I'd like to mention, since you're working with rendering music in the browser, that you should take a look at www.vexflow.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this javascript to your `<script></script>`:

```
$(function(){ $("#randomize").click(); });
```

This will cause your page to run the function that populates your random elements then (at the end of that function) run the scale function.

I tested it by running it on your page in the chrome console and it worked.

Comment: This sort of fixed the issue.  By firing `$("#randomize").click()` on page load, the initial running of the script that does not work occurs.  Now, when I click the randomize button, the code works as expected, because the script has run once already.  The only issue is I would eventually like the site to display a random rhythm on page load.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a breakpoint in the `scaleRhythm` function you'll notice on page load it's not being run. You've defined the function but it is not being called on page load. In fact none of the code you want run (ie: the ajax call) gets called until the first click happens. So what you need to do is trigger the `click` event on the button like JRulle said.

```
$("#randomize").click();
```

Comment: I tried this in chrome and the OP actually needs to run the whole randomize function on load, not just scaleRhythm()

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here is your issue.
The first time you click the button, `var rhythmWidth = $("#rhythm").width();` evaluates to "0" because it is empty.

Which causes these subsequent functions to be "0" as well:

```
var ratio =   screenWidth / rhythmWidth;
var newHeight = (400 * ratio) * .9;
```

I would edit your function to be like so:

```
var rhythmWidth = $("#rhythm").width();
if (rhythmWidth == 0) { rhythmWidth = 10; } //assign some reasonable value here
```

since your function does not support a rhythmWidth of "0"

Comment: I did some further debugging, and I noticed that sometimes the code works, and sometimes it doesn't.  I think the issue is occuring because the `scaleRhythm` function is executing before all of the images load, which is causing a problem with the calculations.  As an experiment, I wrapped my 'scaleRhythm' function in a `setTimeout` function with 1000ms.  This works, however, the images are displayed at their full (too large) resolution for a moment before resizing.  Is there a way I can make this function wait to run until all of the images have finished loading?

Comment: What if you make the individual images `display: none;` in the css? This would let you add them and run your sizing calculations without the incorrect sizing flicker (because hidden elements can still be sized and manipulated) and then at the end of your function, you can show everything.

Comment: That did it!  Actually, I ended up using `opacity:0;` instead of `display:none;` since `#rhythm` is the parent of the `.note` elements, and ended up with a width of 0, which threw off the calculations.  Thanks a bunch!